# Bind a List of object using Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have razor pages . 
I have prepared in a handler a list of(visitorTypes)
I only want to bind them . there is something that i have missed , but i dont know what

Here is my c# code

```
[ModelBinder(Name ="Visitors")]
public ICollection<VisitorType> VisitorTypes { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnGetListOfVisitorTypeAsync()
{
    VisitorTypes = _db.VisitorTypes.ToList();
    return RedirectToPagePermanent("/Visitors",VisitorTypes);
}
```

And here is my razor page

```
<div class="container">
        <form method="get"  asp-page-handler="ListOfVisitorType" >
        @foreach (var item in Model.VisitorTypes)
        {
            <label>@item.VisitorTypeName.ToString() </label>
        }
            </form>
    </div>
```

can someone please explain what im doing wrong 
(I have tried to return the list , i have tried to make it a void method , but none of them works with me )

Here Is The modal

```
  private string _VisitorTypeName { get; set; }
    public string VisitorTypeName { get {return _VisitorTypeName; } set { _VisitorTypeName = value; } }
    ICollection<Visitor> Visitors { get; set; }
```

Comment: why u use `RedirectToPagePermanent`?

Comment: i dont know im still new , i think it will load to bing the data again

Comment: could you please add your `Model`? in your question

Comment: What page is the first section of C# code in?

Comment: @markdibe Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. It also lacks a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi I only want to sort a list of object in the razor page

Comment: @markdibe have you reviewed the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#writing-a-basic-form

Answer (score 0):

What if you generate your data when your **View** get loaded, something like this:

```
public IActionResult Visitors()
{
    VisitorTypes = _db.VisitorTypes.ToList();
    return View(VisitorTypes);
}
```

Comment: its not an mvc controller , they are razor pages not view controller

Answer (score 0):

You may have passed wrong model with "@model ?" in razor page.

Answer (score -1):

## This is pretty Simple

1. First you need to know how actually MVC works and what it's:

   - MVC is a architectural pattern , we keep all things loosely coupled in terms of MODEL, View and Controller
   - So it's doesn't means that cannot write code directly in "Razor View",
     For example how we write JavaScript directly in HTML or View. for decoupling purpose we create .JS file to separate script code from View(HTML).

## Now comes to actual work

1. First before accessing List(VisitorTypes) it must be declare and initialize with value in the razorview itself

   ```
   @{

     List<VisitorTypes> listVisitorTypes = _db.VisitorTypes.ToList();
   }
   ```

   2. And finally render the list:

      @foreach (var item in listVisitorTypes )
          {
              @item.VisitorTypeName.ToString() 
          }

Comment: Use the above code section and description so you can understand, you can also write code in razorview

Comment: It's not MVC. It's Razor Pages.

Comment: Mike Brind  : that's i'm trying to say dude.. means u can write code through razor ,the person who raise question is thinking like MVC

Comment: You shouldn't write code in a Razor content page anymore than you would in an MVC view.